# Why do I have to pass the self argument when I call a parent method in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, python-3.6

I'm having trouble understanding the logic behind having to type self when I call a a parent class's method:

```
import tkinter as tk 
class myApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
```

Why should I have to type self in:`container = tk.Frame(self)`?

Comment: Because the function is defined to take that argument. The `self` argument is just like any other, indeed, it is only *conventionally* called `self`, but you could call it `this` or `that` or `banana`. The only special thing about it is that it is automagically applied with the instance when called as a method on an instance. When you call the method directly from the class, it is *just another function*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Widgets exist in a tree-like structure. Except for the root window, every widget has a parent.

When creating a widget, the first argument is the parent for the new widget. In this specific case `self` represents the root window. Since it is the only other widget, it's the only choice for the parent of `container`

Comment: Thank you man! I got it. The first argument that the Frame() method takes is the parent window, and as the myApp object instance is the parent window I use self to declare that. Is that right?

Comment: @EduardoZacour: yes.